# UnknownClass.Cucumber while running JUnit engine + Cucumber + Gradle tests from command line

Tags: build.gradle, junit5, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Me and my team just moved from JUnit4 to JUnit5 and we faced with parallelism issues. With 4th version we used -Dcucumber.options="--threads 5" to run in tests several threads, but after deprecation and removing of cucumber options it's obviously doesn't work anymore. I set up (at least I think so) junit platform engine for the project (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#configuration-options), but when I try to run tests via comand line (using Gradle task), I receive following error:

```
UnknownClass.Cucumber > UnknownClass.initializationError FAILED
    org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException at EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:114
        Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException at HierarchicalTestEngine.java:57
            Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException at DefaultParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy.java:41
```

Unfortunately, didn't find something in the internet, maybe someone can help with it?

What we use:

- Spring boot 2.7.3
- Gradle 7.5.1
- Cucumber java, junit, spring, junit-platform-engine 5.7.0
- junit-platform-suite-api 1.3.2

Tasks in build.gradle that I have now:

```
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty("cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy", "long")
    systemProperty("cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled", true)
    systemProperty("cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy", "fixed")
    systemProperty("cucumber.plugin", "html:reports/html")
    systemProperty("cucumber.plugin", "pretty")
    systemProperty("cucumber.plugin", "junit:reports/junit")
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            mainClass.set("io.cucumber.core.cli.Main")
            classpath = cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.test.get().output + sourceSets.main.get().output
        }
    }
}
tasks {
    val consoleLauncherTest by registering(JavaExec::class) {
        dependsOn(testClasses)
        val reportsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results")
        outputs.dir(reportsDir)
        classpath = sourceSets["test"].runtimeClasspath
        mainClass.set("org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher")
        args("--scan-classpath")
        args("--include-engine", "cucumber")
        args("--reports-dir", reportsDir)
    }
    test {
        dependsOn(consoleLauncherTest)
        exclude("**/*")
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("com/example")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example")
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [IntegrationContext::class], loader = SpringBootContextLoader::class)
class Application() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty much impossible to answer because you didn't go through the process of making a minimal reproducer. For your next question please read the "Help others reproduce the problem" section in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.).

> With 4th version we used -Dcucumber.options="--threads 5" to run in tests several threads, but after deprecation and removing of cucumber options it's obviously doesn't work anymore.

Project typically include a [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) and [release notes](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v5.0.0.md#property-based-options) documenting all [relevant changes](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v6.0.0.md#removal-of-cucumberoptions).

> What we use:
>
> - Spring boot 2.7.3
> - Cucumber java, junit, spring, junit-platform-engine 5.7.0
> - junit-platform-suite-api 1.3.2

These dependencies don't converge and aren't quite correct. You'll want to use Cucumber's and JUnit's Bill of Materials to avoid having to specify the version for every module.

If you're using Spring Boot in the recommended way you may also be able to omit the `junit-bom` altogether.

```kotlin
dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation(platform("io.cucumber:cucumber-bom:7.9.0"))

    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}
```

> Tasks in build.gradle that I have now:

So in this build file it appears that you are trying to run Cucumber in 3 different ways. Through the JUnit Platform, through Cucumbers CLI and through the JUnit 5 ConsoleLauncher.

I don't know which solution you are trying use but suppose that you want to use the JUnit Platform, then you look at [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) for a working example.

Then afterwards you should clean up your build file. :D